Generar arbol a partir de sql en ksh
Este código únicamente muestra el primer nivel y las hojas del primer elemento de dicho nivel que está directamente conectado a la raíz (el más a la izquierda).
¿Podrían indicarme qué error estoy cometiendo? Les agradezco mucho de antemano.
PRC_SECUENCIA=$1

Inp_OraServicio=IGRI
Inp_OraSep=$SQL_IFS




Inp_OraServicio=IGRI
Inp_OraSep=$SQL_IFS
Inp_OraSql="SELECT SECUENCIA FROM IGRI.BOL_INC_DE_RED WHERE
SEC_BOLETIN_RAIZ='${PRC_SECUENCIA}' 
ORDER BY SECUENCIA"

IFS=$__SL
  set -- ${Out_Comentario}
IFS=${__IFS}

array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA}


for __derivado in "${@}"
do

 array=${array[@]},${__derivado}

print -r -- "${__derivado}" >> /users/cairo/OmegaCAIRO/bin/GesOPV2/FunEntAstro/pbaFunciones/arbol.log
FunEnt_OPV_getIgriTicketDerivados_Arbol ${__derivado}

done

El problema es que solo visuliza el primer nivel del árbol, y la rama más a la izquierda hasta el final, así:
si mi árbol es:
1
1.1                                          1.2
1.1.1, 1.1.2                                     1.2.1 , 1.2.2
Visualiza: 1,1.1,1.1.1,1.1.2
No visuliza: 1.2.1,1.2.2
